# Get day works wrong in case new Date(year, month, day)

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get day of week by :

```
const date = new Date('2021/12/06')
date.getDay()
```

and it works properly , but when I create date by using `new Date(2021, 12, 6)` , it show me wrong number - `4` . Why is it happens , or I don't understand some exception for this way of creating date object ?

Answer (score 3):

this is because month should be the month index (0 - 11) not the month order (1-12):

```
new Date(2021, 11, 6).getDay()
```

and not

```
new Date(2021, 12, 6).getDay()
```

REF: [Date() constructor: syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax)

Comment: @RandyCasburn OP seems to assume that `new Date('2021/12/06')` is the same as `new Date(2021,12,6)`; but it's not, Abdennour correctly explains what is wrong with that thought, and shows that **after the month fix**, the results are as expected.

Comment: super strange that it doesn't show any exception , when you pass wrong number

Comment: It just rolls over to the next year which allows for adding months to the date `const d = new Date(); d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 12)` so there's no exception to throw.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a date by 3 params you have to use a month INDEX. Starting by 0.

So December is actually 11, not 12.

If you use `new Date(2021, 11, 6)` you get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

getDay() gets the index of the week.  Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.  (0, 1, 2,3,...)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

I believe what you're looking for is getDate()
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp